# Combining types in scala

Tags: scala, f#

I saw that in F# its very easy to define a type which is a combined from a set of other types such as

```ml
type MyFiveNumbers = One | Two | Three | Four | Five
```

This looks just great!

What is the simplest way to do that in Scala?

Comment: @ildjarn It isn't a duplicate of that question, because this is F# syntax for _tagged_ unions.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov : In F# they're the same thing, so if the question is about an equivalent to F# then it is a duplicate.

Comment: @ildjarn As far as I know, F# doesn't have untagged unions at all. E.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233230.aspx only mentions discriminated (tagged) unions.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov : Apologies, this was a confusion of terminology on my part. You're right, an enum is probably the best match in this case (when there's no associated data); otherwise one probably must subscribe to standard dynamic polymorphism. +1 to your answer.

Comment: @ildjarn You don't have to; with this solution you get pattern matching just as in F#. Dynamic polymorphism is also available if desired. There _are_ some drawbacks, but they are mostly around type inference.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov : One does not preclude the other; you get pattern matching on polymorphic types in F# as well, via `?:`. I feel like you're talking in circles, changing between semantics and syntax. I already agreed with you about my misunderstanding of the OP's intention regarding tagged vs. untagged unions, but it appears to me that you're now calling (or continuing to call) into question the syntax, which as I said, is the _same_ in F# for both - the `match` expression. Or maybe your point is just lost on me...

Comment: @ildjarn My point here was precisely that one doesn't preclude the other and you don't _have_ to "subscribe to standard dynamic polymorphism" (which the comment I replied to seems to be saying).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov : Then we're in agreement it seems, just barred by naivety. ;-]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`One` and the rest are not types, but union cases. The Scala equivalent in fact does make them types:

```
sealed trait MyFiveNumbers

case object One extends MyFiveNumbers

case object Two extends MyFiveNumbers

...
```

In such a simple case you might be best off just using a Java enum. However, if any constructors have parameters (e.g. add `| Other of int` to the end), they correspond to Scala case classes:

```
case class Other(x: Int) extends MyFiveNumbers
```

You can use pattern matching just as in F#:

```
// x has type MyFiveNumbers
x match {
  case One => ...
  ...
  case Other(n) => ...
}
```

and get compiler warnings about incomplete matches (only if the `sealed` keyword is used; otherwise you can create additional cases in other files).